# Progress bar update While button is being pressed

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

After a long time finally i got to know that how to update progress bar while button is being pressed.
This code is not work for gingerbread.
and all the other OS it works fine.
in-case of any question you may ask enjoy!!!!

```
         button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    if(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                        arg0.post(rotationRunnable);

                    }
                    return false;
                }
    });
```

RotationRunnable Method :-

```
 private Runnable rotationRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (button.isPressed()) {
                try{
                if(mProgressStatus<100){
                    Thread.sleep(500);

                    mProgressStatus = doWork();
                    pB.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                }
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                button.postDelayed(rotationRunnable, 40);
            }
        }
    };
```

and finaly DoWork Method :-

```
                      private int doWork() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Timer t=new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mProgressStatus=mProgressStatus+1;
            }
        }, 1000);
        time=mProgressStatus;
        return mProgressStatus;
    }
```

Comment: So, can you confirm the question is, "why doesn't this work on Gingerbread?"

Comment: yup i want that this code also run on Gingerbread but devices that run on Gingerbread OS couldn't show the progress bar .....

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the `Thread.sleep(500)` you are using. It might be blocking the main thread.
Overall your code is a bit confusing to me. You use 3 different things to time your progress (thread.sleep of 500, 40ms of delayed posting and also the timertask)? couldn't you just do

```
private Runnable rotationRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (button.isPressed()) {
            mProgressStatus++;
            pB.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
            button.postDelayed(rotationRunnable, 1000);
        }
    }
};
```